# VHDL Gated Clock how to avoid

Tags: vhdl, clock, fpga

I've received an advice to avoid gated clock because it may cause problems with slacks and timing costraints. But I want to ask what I can consider like a gated clock.
For example:

This code have gated clock because StopCount gate it.

```
process(ModuleCLK)
begin
    if (rising_edge(ModuleCLK) and StopCount = '0') then
       if ModuleEN = '0' then
           RESET <= '0';
           POWER <= '1';
           EN <= '0';
           CLOCK <= '0';
           SERIAL <= '0';
       elsif
```

This code have also gated clock?

```
    process(ModuleCLK)
    begin
        if ModuleEN = '0' then
               RESET <= '0';
               POWER <= '1';
               EN <= '0';
               CLOCK <= '0';
               SERIAL <= '0';
        elsif (rising_edge(ModuleCLK)) then
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The term "gated clock" is often used in ASIC technology for a clock where the clock pulse is only generated when a condition is true (1), so the gated clock is a property of the clock source.  A gated clock can be made with a latch and AND gate, like show below, and that kind of design requires special attention to address the timing issues you mention, thus is not suited for FPGA design:

[image]

The code you have shown uses an enable on the flip-flop to update the flip-flop value depending on the enable, so this is a clock enable, not a gated clock.

The first code can, and should, be written as:

```
process (ModuleCLK) is
begin
    if rising_edge(ModuleCLK) then
        if StopCount = '0' then
            ...  -- Update at clock if StopCount = '0'
```

This reflect how the design is typically implemented in a FPGA, where the flip-flop is always clocked (`ModuleCLK`) but where the output is only updated if the condition (`StopCount = '0'`) is true.

The second code example looks like asynchronous reset, except that the code should have reset condition (`ModuleEN`) in the sensitivity list (missing in the question code).  The asynchronous reset occurs since no clock clock is required for the flip-flops to change value; the only requirement is that the reset condition is true, and then a change of value occurs asynchronously to any clock.

So a way to properly write flip-flops in VHDL, with input `a` and output `z`, is like:

```
process (reset, clock) is
begin
  if reset = '1' then
    z <= '0';
  elsif rising_edge(clock) then
    if enable = '1' then
      z <= a;
    end if;
  end if;
end process;
```

In Altera Quartus II this creates RTL figure like:

[image]

The implementation in an Arria II device is then:

[image]

This shows that the flip-flop up actually updated at every rising edge of the clock, so the clock enable is implemented through a combinatorial design (LUT), where the current data is feed back to the flip-flop when enable is false (0), or new data is given from `a` when enable is true (1).

Comment: Also, the second example should have `ModuleEN` in the sensitivity list.