# Gated Clock in Clock Divider for a Square Wave

Tags: time, vhdl, clock, fpga, xilinx-ise

I recently have been designing a clock divider for my system - which I redesigned, and now has an asynchronous reset, which generates a synchronous reset for the rest of the system. To do this, I followed the [answers & advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34067276/synchronous-vs-asynchronous-resets-in-fpga-system) to my own question and used a clock enable to toggle an output, thus generating clock with a 50% duty cycle (which is desired).

However, this has thrown up the error when generating the bitstream of 
`PhysDesignRules:372 - Gated clock. Clock net ... is sourced by a combinatorial pin. This is not good design practice. Use the CE pin to control the loading of data into the flip-flop.`

Reading into this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15244992/vhdl-creating-a-very-slow-clock-pulse-based-on-a-very-fast-clock) about using the clock enable, it appears when creating a clock enable is correct, however, because I need a square wave (and not just a 1/200MHz pulse), and thus using the enable to toggle another signal, it appears in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29674828/vhdl-gated-clock-how-to-avoid) that this is an intentional gated clock.

So my questions are; is this gated clock warning significant? Both in simulation, and on an oscilloscope it appears to function correctly (so I'm inclined to ignore it), but am I storing problems for later? Is there a way of getting a very slow 50% duty cycle pulse without a gated clock?

I've put my code below!

Thanks very much (especially to the handful of people who have collectively given a lot of time to my recent non-stop questions)

David

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
library UNISIM;
use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

ENTITY CLK_DIVIDER IS
    GENERIC(INPUT_FREQ : INTEGER;
            OUT1_FREQ  : INTEGER;
            OUT2_FREQ  : INTEGER
    );
    PORT(SYSCLK      : IN  STD_LOGIC;
         RESET_N     : IN  STD_LOGIC;
         RESET_N_OUT : OUT STD_LOGIC;
         OUT1        : OUT STD_LOGIC;
         OUT2        : OUT STD_LOGIC);
END CLK_DIVIDER;

architecture Behavioral of Clk_Divider is
    constant divider1 : integer   := INPUT_FREQ / OUT1_FREQ / 2;
    constant divider2 : integer   := INPUT_FREQ / OUT2_FREQ / 2;
    signal counter1   : integer   := 0;
    signal counter2   : integer   := 0;
    signal output1    : std_logic := '0';
    signal output2    : std_logic := '0';
    signal reset      : boolean;
begin
    reset_proc : process(RESET_N, SYSCLK)
        variable cycles        : integer := 0;
        variable reset_counter : integer := 0;
    begin
        if rising_edge(SYSCLK) then
            if cycles < 2 then
                if reset_counter >= divider1 then
                    cycles        := cycles + 1;
                    reset_counter := 0;
                else
                    reset_counter := reset_counter + 1;
                end if;
                reset <= true;
            else
                reset <= false;
            end if;
        end if;
        if RESET_N = '0' then
            cycles        := 0;
            reset_counter := 0;
            reset         <= true;
        end if;
    end process;

    output1_proc : process(SYSCLK)
    begin
        if rising_edge(SYSCLK) then
            if counter1 >= divider1 - 1 then
                output1  <= not output1;
                counter1 <= 0;
            else
                counter1 <= counter1 + 1;
            end if;
            if RESET_N = '0' then
                counter1 <= 0;
                output1  <= '1';
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

    output2_proc : process(SYSCLK)
    begin
        if rising_edge(SYSCLK) then
            if counter2 >= divider2 - 1 then
                output2  <= not output2;
                counter2 <= 0;
            else
                counter2 <= counter2 + 1;
            end if;
            if RESET_N = '0' then
                counter2 <= 0;
                output2  <= '1';
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

    OUT1        <= output1;
    OUT2        <= output2;
    RESET_N_OUT <= '0' when reset else '1';

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Wasn't this question here a few days ago? But, I cannot find it anymore???

Comment: I don't think so? I certainly haven't asked it before, and I did quite a wide search before asking a question that's already quite closely related to the other questions I mentioned.

Comment: It was a question of another user. Nevermind. Your code works fine with ISE 14.7. So which tool are you using?

Comment: I'm synthesizing with XST. The exact complaint comes from Clk_Div/output2...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments suggest, that the clock-divider is instantiated in a larger design.
If you want to use the generated clock there, you must add a BUFG between signal `output2` and the output `out2` like this:

```
out2_bufg : BUFG port map(I => output2, O => out2);
```

The component BUFG is defined in the library `unisim.vcomponents`. Same applies to output `out1`.

The BUFG ensures, that the generated clock is distributed using a clock-tree, so that the clock signal arrives at all destination flip-flops at the same time. This minimizes hold-time violations and gives more room for the setup of data signals.

If you still get the warning/error, then you combined the generated clock signal with another signal elsewhere in the larger design.

Answer (score 1):

The `reset_proc` process is written with a `elsif cycles > 1 then` outside the clocked part, and with the condition derived from `cycles` which is also assigned as part of reset.  It is unclear what hardware is actually described here, but it makes the synthesis tool unhappy.

If you want to use `RESET_N` as asynchronous reset, then just make a simple `if RESET_N = '0' then ... end if;`, and assign whatever signals or variables required to be reset.  Other assignments should be moved to the clocked part.

NOTE: Code was changed after the above update... which may have removed the reason for the question.

Btw. `RESET_N` is used as asynchronous reset in the `reset_proc`, but as synchronous reset in the other processes, and this inconsistent use looks like there may be a potential problem with the reset scheme.

Comment: Hang on - I'm very, very sorry - I've used the wrong code there! Let me update it!

Comment: But yes, I completely see about the asynchronous reset, hence the reason for changing the code!

Comment: After code update: Do you still get the warning "PhysDesignRules:372 - Gated clock. Clock net ... is sourced by a combinatorial ..."?

Comment: Yes. I still get the gated clock warning. I changed the code because I posted old code from before I attempted to debug it myself! Sincere apologies for the confusion

Comment: With Xilinx ISE 14.6 the warning does not show after code update, while it did before.

Comment: Then it must be the case, that the error is actually caused elsewhere in the system?